# Understanding Type Members

Tags: scala

Given a trait:

```
scala> trait Fn { 
     |  type A
     |  type B
     |  def f(x: A): B
     | }
defined trait Fn
```

I'd like to override `Fn` with another `trait` such that:

- if `A` is a `String`, then `B` must be an `Int`, otherwise make `B`'s type a `Boolean`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are thinking of type members more than they are. I don't think you can do the stuff you want, at least not in the same class.

Type members should be defined in the end class, and I don't think you can do it variable.

But you **can** make it interesting:

```
  trait Fn {
      type A
      type B
      def f(x: A): B
     }

  implicit object Bn extends Fn {
    type A = String
    type B = Int

    def f(x: A): B = 5
  }

  implicit object Cn extends  Fn {
    type A = Int
    type B = Boolean

    def f(x: A): B = true
  }

  def fun[C](c: C)(implicit f: Fn { type A = C}) = {
    println(f.f(c))
  }


  fun[String]("H") // prints 5 (calls Bn). A = String, B = Int
  fun[Int](55)     // prints true (calls Cn). A = Int, B = Boolean
```